# XIB will not create UIWebView and is always nil

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, null

I am at a loss.  I have a UIViewController with a UIWebView in it.  When I run the application the UIWebView is never instantiated.  Everything else comes up fine.  Has anyone seen this before?

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.  The UIWebView does not instantiated UNTIL it is displayed.  I was trying to load the website before I pushed the view controller into the navigation controller.