# Swift UIWebView Optional is nil

Tags: uiwebview, nsstring, swift

In the below example, `infoScroller` is a `UIWebView` and `println(HTMLDescription)` prints a lovely string of HTML. However, the attempt to `loadHTMLString` gets the runtime error: `fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None`

```
if let HTMLDescription = self.myData?.content? {
    println(HTMLDescription)
    infoScroller.loadHTMLString(HTMLDescription, baseURL: nil)
}
```

I've tried every combination of `!` and `?` in both the assignment and use of the string but I get this same error every time, though the variable never fails to print out perfectly to the console.

There is another value that I set using the same method and it works fine. Both are strings, but the other one is more simple in that `HTMLDescription` is multiline and the working one is not.

Edit: The discussion in the comments prompted me to check the `infoScroller` and it's description as printed in the console is: `(@sil_weak UIWebView!) infoScroller =`

I'm thinking that's the issue, but I'm not sure what it means or how to fix it.

Edit 2: This has to be the issue. `println(infoScroller.description)` yields the exact same error.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the `baseUrl:nil` part?

Comment: I don't think so. I tried writing the string straight to a `UITextView` earlier and the error was the same.

Comment: My guess is infoScroller is optional (and nil)

Comment: @David The error would be `'UIWebView?' does not have a member named 'loadHTMLString'`.

Comment: The web view is in the storyboard and bound to `@IBOutlet var infoScroller:UIWebView`. I'm relatively sure that means it's not optional?

Comment: `@IBOutlet` implicitly marks your property as both `weak` and optional.

Comment: The following code works for me: https://gist.github.com/akashivskyy/1df3d055e37aaf3e2796. Check for any differences on how the variables are declared, etc.

Comment: Well, something has to be different because that's just about the same as my class structure, but I'm not seeing what the difference is. :/

Comment: Just to note, I think Swift properties are strong by default as discussed in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html

Comment: Try `if let HTMLDescription = self.myData?.content`  That format is used to unbox an optional and will result in HTMLDescription not being optional.  As it stands I think it's going to still be optional, so passing it to loadHTMLString is trying to implicitly unbox it hence the error?

Comment: No dice, @David. I've also tried both `!`, both `?` and a bunch of other combinations to no avail. I tried running `.copy()` in the assignment too.

Comment: @akashivskyy notwithstanding, my reading of `loadHTMLString()` is that `baseURL` is an `NSURL!` and thus you cannot pass a nil to it.  The `println` works, right?  What does the debugger say `HTMLDescription`  is when you stop it in here?

Comment: @iluvcapra I've seen this done several times before. I don't think that's the issue. However, I think the `infoScroller` is `nil` so I'm back to looking into that. Thought it couldn't be optional but I guess it is.

Comment: Check that in the debugger -- you may be able to pass nil for baseURL at this time and in this circumstance, but only because the function is not running, and it may work in some other cases because the function is internally never trying to unwrap it.  But passing nil there is a loaded gun, the host is telling you straight up he's gonna try to use that parameter and the runtime will crash hard if he tries and it isn't filled.

Comment: Description as printed: `(@sil_weak UIWebView!) infoScroller =`

We are now officially in new territory for me. I don't know what that means.

Comment: @iluvcapra `NSURL!` is an 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional'. The only difference between that and an 'Optional' is that you can reference it directly without unwrapping it, but it will produce a runtime error if it is nil. So it can store 'nil' it will just produce an error when it is used.

Comment: Exactly, and you have no control over wether the host uses it or not, putting `nil` there *may* work but there's no promise that it'll succeed or fail this time, and you're not fulfilling the API contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095529/xib-will-not-create-uiwebview-and-is-always-nil) put me on the path. I was trying to load the content before the view was fully loaded. Moved `loadHTMLString()` into `viewDidLoad()`. Stupid simple.